# Repairs during raids - What are my options?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any other way to have repairs in raid besides Jeeves or Reins of the Traveler's Tundra Mammoth?

Are my only repair options for raids:

- Jeeves
- Reins of the Traveler's Tundra Mammoth
- Hearthstone, repair, port back in via warlock summons?

**What options do I have besides these 3 things?**

*Note:* I am not talking about LFR. I'm talking about N, H, and M raiding

Comment: Been a while since I've played, but unless they removed the lower level Engineer bots, engineers can create cheaper repair bots if they don't have Jeeves, or he is on cool-down.

Comment: Mage portals...

Comment: I don't believe there are other repair bots in the game anymore (besides Walter). Taking a mage portal is basically the same as hearthing back. As far as I know, the question lists the only ways of doing this.

Comment: @klm123 That is a pet battle ability, not something you can use to repair your equipment.

Comment: @twobugs According to WoWHead, Field Repair Bot 110G was still in the game as of patch 6.0.3.  Haven't checked the others.

Comment: For that matter, Jeeves takes 2xField Repair Bot 74A and 10xField Repair Bot 110G as ingredients..

Comment: LFRaid or full Premade? LFRaid gives you addl' options.

Comment: Again, haven't really played since Cata days, but usually there is a vender who can repair either right inside the raid instance, or near the entrance to the raid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the ones you mentioned (and mage portal mentioned in comments), here are your other two options, both made with Engineering:

[Field-Repair-Bot-74a](http://www.wowhead.com/item=18232/field-repair-bot-74a)

[Field-Repair-Bot-110g](http://www.wowhead.com/item=34113/field-repair-bot-110g)

Note of course that the mount is only available in "outside" environments. These two repair bots also share a cooldown, according to Wowhead.